# How to organize data in a java JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

I've searched and searched about this topic, but have found nothing. How would I organize things like buttons and text fields in a Java JFrame?

EDIT: Sorry, this was incredibly vague. I've seen the Layout Managers but I want to be able to put the components in a specific place, not where the Layout Managers want to put it. Maybe I've overlooked something, but with the BorderLayout it puts buttons across the entire window, despite my attempt to use a `setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(x,y)`.

Comment: Have a look at layouts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: `"I've searched and searched about this topic, but have found nothing."` Sorry, but this means that you will want to work to improve your searching skills. Seriously. I mean a basic [organize components in a JFrame](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=organize%20components%20in%20a%20jframe) Google search will bring you all you need to know. That's just a search using the terms that you've used in asking this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, my original question was extremely vague. I have edited.

Comment: The answer depends on what you want the GUI to look like, but you can nest JPanels with different Swing layout managers to get various GUIs.

Comment: I just researched that a bit, and think that will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)! Also, use NetBeans IDE to draw your GUI. Has nice drag-and-drop lists of widgets.

The link above is a visual guide.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited explaining in better detail what I need.